# How to read data from dropdown list in googlesheets4?

Tags: r, googlesheets4

There is a spreadsheet that has a dropdown of values

| Fruits | Colors |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Blue |
| Pear | Red |

Whenever I try to use `read_sheet`, all these values come up as NA. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `col_type = "c"` (character) for the column in question. The other `col_type` arguments will lead to `NA`s.